# C# Cross-Class object

Tags: c#

I'm working on very simple Roguelike game (just for myself) and get a question:

As it is not possible to create a cross-class struct-object (entity in the game case) that could be accessible from any class of my program, what to use to create a cross-class object? I was thinking of something like storing all newly created object (enities) in a static object array, but I guess there is more simple solution on this problem.

Question itself: How to create a cross-class accessible object(s) with your own properties?

Thanks everybody, I found what I was searching for.

Comment: Are you asking what a global variable is, or how to make one?

Comment: A _cross class_ object is a **public class**

Comment: More than a static object array, a `Dictionary` or similar seems a better option. If you do not want to make it static, you may use the singleton pattrn.

Comment: An object that can be accessed from any class is a class, so what is the question?

Comment: Any time you find yourself drawn toward creating global mutable state, take a moment to step back and consider whether that's really the best way to approach things.  Does everything in the program need to have access to this state or is there a logical subsection of the program that needs it?  Pretend your classes are in the CIA and information should only be shared on a need-to-know basis; this reduces the chances that some class in another area of the project decides to break something you were using.

Comment: For me it is totally unclear what you are trying to achieve. The main reason for this is that you make up terminology that doesn't exist, like "cross-class struct-object", "cross-class object" or "cross-class accessible object".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you tried passing around a value type (a `struct`) between different classes and you noticed that when you update the value in one place it doesn't change the value in another place.

That's the basic difference between [value types and reference types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d43ts61%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

If you are creating the `struct` yourself you may want to instead define it as a class.

If not, you could wrap all your structs in a class and pass the class around as your state object.

If all you have is simply a list of the same type of struct (like Points), just pass the List itself around.  C# collections are implemented as classes.

```
public class GameState
{
    public Point PlayerLocation { get; set; }
    public List<Point> BulletPoints { get; set; }
    public double Health { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can create a GameState and pass it around to different classes:

```
public class Game
{
    private GameState _state = new GameState();
    private BulletUpdater _bulletUpdater = new BulletUpdater();

    public void Update()
    {
        _bulletUpdater.UpdatePoints(_state);

        // Points have now been modified by another class, even though a Point is a struct.
    }
}

public class BulletUpdater
{
    public void UpdatePoints(GameState state)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < state.BulletPoints.Count; i++)
        {
            Point p = state.BulletPoints[i];
            state.BulletPoints[i] = new Point(p.X + 1, p.Y + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Just remember in the above code if I were to write:

```
Point p = state.BulletPoints[i];
p.X += 1;
p.Y += 1;
```

That wouldn't affect the original point!  When you read a value type from a list or from a class into only copies the value into a local variable.  So in order to reflect your changes in the original object stored inside the reference type you need to overwrite it like so:

```
state.BulletPoints[i] = p;
```

This same principal is why the following also will not work:

```
state.PlayerLocation.X += 5; // Doesn't do anything
state.PlayerLocation.Y += 5; // Also doesn't do anything
```

The compiler would tell you in this case that you are doing something wrong.  You are only modifying the returned value of the property, not the backing field itself.  You have to write it like so:

```
state.PlayerLocation = new Point(state.PlayerLocation.X + 5, state.PlayerLocation.Y + 5); // This works!
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

1. Using IoC Framework, like [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/). You can setup Ninject to create single instance for all usages.
2. The other option is to use [Singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) design pattern
3. And the third one is to use static property

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. What about `public` and `static` class?

```
public static class CrossClassObject
{
   public static object MyProperty { get; set; }

   public static void MyMethod() {}
}
```

Of course this class should be placed in the same namespace that other ones.

How to use it?

```
class OtherClassInTheSameNamespace
{
   private void SomeMethod()
   {
      var localVariable = CrossClassObject.MyProperty; // get 'cross-class' property MyProperty

      CrossClassObject.MyMethod(); // execute 'cross-class' method MyMethod()
   }
}
```

Comment: Don't use public fields, use public properties.

Answer (score 0):

No idea what you are trying to achieve... but if you want a list of objects accessible 'cross-class', just make a static class with a list of objects and then when you reference your class from any other class, you will have access to its list of objects. Here is something like that:

```
public static class ObjectController
{
    private static IList<object> existingObjects;

    public static IList<object> ExistingObjects
    {
        get 
        {
            if (existingObjects == null)
            {
                existingObjects = new List<object>();
            }
        }
    }
}

public class MyObject
{
    public MyObject()
    {
        ObjectController.ExistingObjects.Add(this);
    }

    public void Delete()
    {
        ObjectController.ExistingObjects.Remove(this);
    }
}
```

Then you can add stuff like

```
MyObject newObj = new MyObject();
//// other stuff... This object should now be visible to whatever other class references ObjectController
newObj.Delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use the Singleton pattern:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Here is an example of what this would look like in C#:

```
public class Singleton
{
    static Singleton()
    {
        Instance = new Singleton();
    }

    public static Singleton Instance { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: Bit over complex (no need for `static` constructor, just use `readonly static` field), and at the same time too simple (constructor should be `private` and class should be `sealed`).

Comment: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx for all the options though. Although doesn't include version I suggest!